# Which hazards are solved by instruction reordering?

Tags: compilers, cpu-pipelines

I am not clear on whether it's data and control hazards, or control hazards only. Also, the "solved" word confuses me - technically, instruction reordering is used to solve dependences and thus prevent hazards from happening in the first place. Once they do happen, though, it's stalls and forwarding. Would that make the answer "None"?

Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Did you really mean to use the [tag:compilers] tag?  Are you asking about instruction reordering by hardware inside the pipeline or by the compiler?  (In my answer I'm assuming you are asking about hardware reordering, not compiler instruction scheduling.  The "hazards" terminology is typically only used by computer architects.)  (Not that the answer is significantly different if you really meant compilers.)

Comment: I'm not sure, this is an exam question. And that's precisely what's bugging me: I don't know what it means in the first place. At first I thought it was static (compiler) reordering, but now I think it might be about Tomasulo and scoreboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instruction reordering in cpu-pipelines doesn't solve any hazards problem.

[Register renaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) eliminates write-after-write data hazards on registers and write-after-read data hazards on registers.

[Speculative execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) tries to find some useful work to do in the presence of control hazards.

Instruction reordering only works between instructions that are already completely independent of one another (either because they work with completely different registers or because after register renaming they don't need any of the same registers).  At best I would say that instruction reordering solves a "bookkeeping hazard" (I just made that term up).  The reason you would *not* do instruction reordering dynamically in the pipeline is if the bookkeeping hardware to do instruction reordering is too expensive for one reason or another.  Issuing instructions in-order is cheaper (in terms of hardware) than implementing the queues and logic to do out-of-order issue.

Comment: OK, to clarify: dynamic/hardware instruction scheduling -> scoreboard & Tomasulo. I just now realised the difference.
I suppose that would throw forwarding out of the picture, since there is none in sb and Tomasulo?

Comment: Yes.  dynamic/hardware instruction scheduling -> scoreboard & Tomasulo.  "Forwarding" in a simple 5-stage in-order pipeline is equivalent to out-of-order _completion_ and _write-back_ from the functional units to the register file in sb or Tomasulo. We just don't call it "forwarding", because there's simply no way in sb or Tomasulo to force the individual functional units to _not_ write back as soon as they are finished.